# Typescript error: Assigning values to object properties in a loop

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to loop over the properties of an object and overwrite an existing object of the same type.
It works in the runtime, but Typescript says:

`pet2[key]: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)`

```
type Pet = { name: string; age: number };
const pet1: Pet = { name: 'Speedy', age: 4 };
const pet2: Pet = { name: 'Bibi', age: 5 };

// overwrite manually - no typescript error:
pet2['name'] = pet1['name'];
pet2['age'] = pet1['age'];

// overwrite with a loop - typescript error:
const keys = Object.keys(pet1) as Array<keyof Pet>;
for (const key of keys) 
    pet2[key] = pet1[key];
```

How can I achieve this with a loop, so that Typescript doesnt complain?

To me it looks like Typescript evaluates all possible types on the right side of the assignment (string | number) and then tries to combine all properties of the left side (string & number) and comes the the conclusion: (string | number) doesnt fit (never).

Edit:
This is just a simplified version of my problem. I run into this problem over and over again. Today i ran into it with a svelte-store-subscribe:

```
for (const filterColum of filterColumns)
    selected[filterColum].subscribe(($value) => { $selected[filterColum] = $value })
```

Comment: You'll be happiest using `Object.assign(pet2, pet1)` and not using a manual loop.  Otherwise you need to avoid the correlated union issue, which TS only supports via generics, leading to the awful version [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0OVqN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you. If your provided version is really the only solution to this typescript problem, then I think I have to stick with ts-ignore.
Btw. I edited my post. This typescript problem comes in a variety of which most of them are not solved with Object.assign or Object.fromEntries.

Comment: Well, `forEach()` on an array is a little less terrible, since it involves the callback more naturally, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wEjYyN).  It definitely is annoying though.  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known pain point of TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693).  When you have two objects `pet1` and `pet2` of type `Pet`, and a key `key` of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) assignable to `keyof Pet`, the compiler will not generally let you write

```
pet2[key] = pet1[key]; // error!
```

because it doesn't pay attention to the fact that `key` is the very same *value* on either side.  It treats it like you might have two keys `key1` and `key2`, both of the same union type:

```
pet2[key2] = pet1[key1]; // error
```

And you want *that* to be an error, because if `keyof Pet` is `"name" | "age"`, then you want to avoid the situation where `key1` is `"name"` while `key2` is `"age"` and you assign a number to a string property.

It would be very nice if the compiler could distinguish those two assignments, since one is always safe and the other rarely is.  But until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#32693 is addressed, you'll need to work around it.

---

The easiest workaround for the example as given is to forget about loops and just use [the `Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) like `Object.assign(pet2, pet1)`.  But if you need to have something looplike in your code, that won't work.

---

The general recommended approach to situations like this where you want the compiler to keep track of correlated union types is to refactor to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead.  So if  `Obj[keyof Obj]` doesn't work, you can try `Obj[K]` where `K extends keyof Obj`:

```
(Object.keys(pet1) as Array<keyof Pet>).forEach(
  <K extends keyof Pet>(key: K) => {
    pet2[key] = pet1[key];
  });
```

Here I'm using [the `forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) because it takes a callback and that's a convenient place to put generics.  You could stick with [a `for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) but it's much clunkier to use:

```
const keys = Object.keys(pet1) as Array<keyof Pet>;
for (const key of keys) {
  (<K extends keyof Pet>(key: K) => { pet2[key] = pet1[key] })(key);
}
```

---

If none of those are to your liking, you are always free to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to appease the compiler, such as the following assertion that `pet2` is of [the intentionally loose `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

```
for (const key of keys)
  (pet2 as any)[key] = pet1[key];  // okay
```

Note that it is generally *not* recommended to use [the `//@ts-ignore` compiler directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) to silence an error unless it's the only way for you to proceed.  The `//@ts-ignore` directive is like putting a piece of tape over a warning light; it does not actually resolve the error, it just prevents you from seeing it, and can cause weird things to happen elsewhere in the code.  It also cannot be used to silence a particular error; anything else that's wrong on the same line will be ignored:

```
for (const key of keys)
  //@ts-ignore
  pet3[key] - pet1[kay]; // okay?!
```

Presumably you'd like to get some kind of warning on undeclared variables or incorrect operators.  As it says in the handbook documentation for `//@ts-ignore`, "we recommend you use these comments *very sparingly*".

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChxQLxQN5QHYEMC2EBcUAzsAE4CW6A5gNxSaX4YCu2ARhCVAL7UBQAxgHt0xKJGABGAnATI0WXAQDkAZUgQAJiCUAaOgwIAWbnyEiE4gEzT4SVBhyMlAITKsyu-YwCsJ3rwB5VgArCH5gADpMQkIySnQACis9cQkASj5eBKDQ8IiAawgQQiT4dLpCKABBEhJMEAAeQpBBADNYeAA+NIjWwRIAUUx+AAsE3igoBoBpKAgAD2AIdA1K5raO4E6E5oJptKRO1AnJsXhLAG1mgF07VKui675Jrgz-M1FmyuQcsMiv0qSA7Raq1epNIobGSdPh9TgJD4IZpQDZfA4oE4JGZzRbLVZQdbtaE7Ip7A6II5oKwPEC3ZD3G7cNIkkBvLj+OFQBHCT5FFHtNGYqwVOjoVk0ulnSQSzK8Tnc8wEvmooqENInAD0GoAAsBCABaOLofoQE7iADMEqg+qlEiu9SeUC1KPy9QA-ABCXhAA)

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I can't believe this simple problem isn't solved yet.
I think i try: (pet2 as any)[key] = pet1[key];
The other solutions are to painfull to write and read for such a simple thing.